# How to use query mysql concat in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to apply concat mysql in my query builder in laravel.

This is my mysql syntax:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
 GROUP_CONCAT(
  DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
        'max(if(date="', 
        date, 
        '", exam, null)) as "',
        date,
        '"'
    )
 ) into @sql
FROM tabelname;
SET @sql = CONCAT("SELECT id_student, ",
                    @sql, " FROM tabelname GROUP BY id_student");

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I've tried with `DB::raw` but got error.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can execute dynamic prepared statements from PHP like this.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are trying which is known as Store Procedure. Yes in PHP also able to make store procedures for CURD operations. But i'm not sure you should make this procedure in laravel ERM. then try to manage your query based on your models and their relationships. otherwise if you didn't start to make your project in Laravel then you should make your store procedures call those procedures in PHP only.